# media query firefox not working

Tags: css, firefox, media-queries

I try to use a media query on Firefox but it doesn't work and it works with Chrome. I have no extension installed so i don't think the problem is here.

This is my media query :

```
@media screen
and (min-width: 1200px)
and (min-device-width: 1200px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
 #live-chat {
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    right: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    z-index:1;
 }
}
```

If you have an idea :) i search since yesterday but find nothing

Regards

Answer (score 1):

try
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { rules }

http://brettjankord.com/2012/11/28/cross-browser-retinahigh-resolution-media-queries/

Comment: Yes it will work, but like i said previously it was -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1 which isn't supported in Firefox

Comment: @media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and ( min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and ( min-resolution: 2dppx) {
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution, thanks to this website : http://mediaqueriestest.com/

(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) is false on Firefox because it's not supported